# How to query non installed rpm file and only package name and version?

Tags: shell-script

I have two different versions of rpm files(1.1.rpm, 2.1.rpm), so here i need to query the rpm and save the output in a text file (1.1.txt , 2.1.txt)and i need to compare both the txt file and show the difference in tabular column.

for eg:

```
Pkg Name                   |      1.1.txt              | 2.1.txt
-------------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------
qq                             |         3.4.4.            | 3.5.5
rr                             |         1.18.1            | 1.18.1
```

I tried this cmd for query

```
rpm -qplv file* > 1.1.txt
```

any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

To obtain the `name` and `version` from an `rpm` package, you use the base `rpm -qp` along with the `--queryformat` option specifying the `%{NAME}` and `%{VERSION}` format specifiers. You can include the field-width modifiers (in the same manner as C `printf`) to provide formatting. You also want to redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` to ignore any rpm signature errors.

For example, to list the name and version for all rpm packages in the current directory:

Example rpms:

```
$ l1 *.rpm
athena-jot-9.0-4.1.x86_64.rpm
freetype2-devel-32bit-2.6.3-5.1.x86_64.rpm
ft2demos-2.6.3-5.1.x86_64.rpm
gtkwrite-0.1.2-2.1.x86_64.rpm
libfreetype6-32bit-2.6.3-5.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Running the command on those loose rpms provides:

```
$ rpm -qp --queryformat "%-24{NAME}%15{VERSION}\n" *.rpm 2>/dev/null
athena-jot                          9.0
freetype2-devel-32bit             2.6.3
ft2demos                          2.6.3
gtkwrite                          0.1.2
libfreetype6-32bit                2.6.3
```

To write it to your `1.1.txt` file, just redirect the output, e.g.

```
$ rpm -qp --queryformat "%-24{NAME}%15{VERSION}\n" *.rpm 2>/dev/null > ~/tmp/1.1.txt

$ cat ~/tmp/1.1.txt
athena-jot                          9.0
freetype2-devel-32bit             2.6.3
ft2demos                          2.6.3
gtkwrite                          0.1.2
libfreetype6-32bit                2.6.3
```

Comment: nice one, but here i did not install the rpm, so when i use this command it just print that rpm name and its version, not for the packages inside the rpm.

Comment: No need to install, you are `-qp` querying the package. They are just a list of rpms I have in a directory that I used for the example.

Comment: i tried this is not helping me